# How to build one to one chat system with django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am seeking guidance on how to build a chat system similar to Facebook using Django. I am a beginner with Django and am finding it more difficult than I anticipated. Is it necessary to use Django Rest Framework for this task? What is the easiest and most robust way to create a chat system with Django? If you have experience building chat systems with Django, please provide helpful suggestions or a comprehensive guide to assist me in this project. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about asking us to "recommend or find a book, ..., **tutorial**.." Your question is very broad and there are likely many opinions on which way is best or easiest, and there's no way to know if an Answer is correct. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

use `Django Channels`, they have tutorial with chat example
https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/index.html